# Scaffolding calling SQL stored procedure in model using ADO.Net

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to ASP.NET (using MVC5 EF 6.1.1) and just developed a new prototype for an app to use at work. I am currently calling my stored procedures in my controllers and was asked to redesign using a Database First approach before my app can go live. I was recommended the following tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/creating-the-web-application

This works great if you select one or more tables from your database on the Entity Data Model Wizard (scaffolding works perfectly). However, I need to select a stored procedure instead of a table and scaffolding won't work. I believe I need to create a partial class in my Model folder to somehow call my stored procedure with its arguments (i.e. var result=dbContext.Procedurename( values1, value2)) but I haven't found a proper example of this and have been blocked at this stage for over a month. Could anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Simple answer dont use stored procedures. With stored procedures you're hiding business logic that shoud be in the application it self.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, that was my first approach but it was refused and I need to stick to Stored Procedures unfortunately...

Comment: @user3253906 using SPs with EF defeats the purpose of EF unfortunately.  It seems more like the feedback you were given was to separate the database logic from the presentation layer, in which case I'd create a layer for EF (ex. Infrastructure) and have the controllers call that instead.  Now if you're still dead set on SPs, take a look at http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx .

Answer (score 1):

Look for `SqlQuery` or `ExecuteSqlCommand`

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<Entity>("spName @param1, @param2, @param3");
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("spName @param1, @param1,@param1");
```

**Better solution:**
Using the wizard to create data model with ADO.Net Entity Framework, along with selecting tables, add stored procedure as well.

[image: adding Stored Procedure using EF]

Doing this will allow us to use context object to execute store procedures in controller.

```
ContosoUniversityEntities context=new ContosoUniversityEntities();
context.mysp();
```

[For your consideration: calling SP in EF](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that sounds like a good idea. but how/where would you call that after creating the EDMX file?

Comment: After creating the .edmx file, go to controller and instantiate your context class. Then use SqlQuery method to execute your stored procedure

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice. This would work fine if I had a few tables only, but the directives I got clearly state that I should only select my Stored Procedures in the "Entity Data Model Wizard" and no tables (since I pull data for so many from different databases) and somehow call my stored procedure in the Model. Any thoughts on how that can be done? I literally haven't found anything on google and I have searched A LOT.

Comment: Ok, I think i have made some progress. Regarding the tutorial recommended, my problem is that my Stored Procedure is stored in a separate dB, so I cannot select any Entites from the drop down.